# Custom Joomla login page

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to create a custom page for login and registration. However, I keep getting the "Invalid Token" error. The form code is copied from the provided login form, and I have this bit near the end of the form:

```
<?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
```

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: Is the data being retrieved from the form correctly?

Comment: Invalid Token may also appear because of an invalid session handler (but if the normal login works, it's no the case)